# SQL: Insert Into with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Let's say I have two tables:

```
Family [idFamily, idPerson] and
Person [idPerson, hasFamily]
```

How can I put the first 5 people from Person who has hasFamily='no' into Family with idFamily=1? I've already figured out that I can use:

```
select * from Person where hasFamily = 'no' limit 5
```

But I'm unsure about the insert part.

(I've already asked this before on http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2sv1n4/sql_question_about_insert_into/ but the solution did not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into family (idFamily, idPerson)
select 1, idPerson 
from Person 
where hasFamily = 'no' 
limit 5
```